# What are good ways to identify the ids of Android UI elements and the xml files they are defined?

Tags: android, android-xml

For example, we have an Android app, and we are now in one activity with its UI pages on the device screen, and we have two buttons.

What are good ways to identify the ids of the two buttons, and the xml files they are defined?
So that I can debug into the class files that use the xml files.

Comment: Could you please explain your question?

Comment: What is your question? What are you expecting as answer? Be more specific

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks!